# What is the integral?

Tags: integration

Which solution is correct for the following integral?

$$\int  -\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx= -\text{arctan}(x)$$

or

$$\int -\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx= \text{arccot}(x)$$

Comment: What do you get when you differentiate the right hand sides?

Comment: Are you forgetting the constant of integration? $arctan(x) = \pi/2 - arccot(x)$

Comment: I do not understand, you mean we need to use antiderivative, but antiderivative in both cases is the same, is not it?

Comment: If I do an integral and get antiderivative $\sin^2(x) +C$, and you do the same integral but get $-\cos^2(x)+C$, are we really getting different answers? (Hint:  we are both computing $\int 2\sin(x) \cos(x) \ dx$.)

Comment: I am sorry but I really confused!!!

Comment: You've already gotten great advice in the first comment:  have you differentiated each answer to see what you get?

Comment: @Nil: the value of integral is $-arctan x +C$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: This is a case where it would REALLY help to point out your confusion and the work you've done to get to that point of confusion.  Otherwise, we're just guessing what your issue is.  (Hence the down/close votes.)  What makes you think this is wrong?

Comment: @Randall, your comment helped me to understand, I really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both integrals are correct. Remember that $$\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$So these functions differ by a constant. If we have two functions that differ by a constant, then the two functions are the anti-derivative of the same functions (in your case $-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$).